# Is there any way to use Saga with new React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-saga

I am excited about new hooks API, but how to handle complex async logic?
Redux-Saga would be a perfect solution if there was any way to use Saga without Redux.

Comment: This is not possible for now. You could always combine hooks and redux+redux-saga in your project.

Answer (score 0):

We are using redux-saga in our current project. It behave as a side-effect and you can configure a callback when an action is dispatched. The callback then do async work from sagas itself. Once there is a response/failure from the service promise, you can dispatch another action which will update the states.